# Impute values on household level based on person level data

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation, mice

I have data on person level and want to impute rent. The rent for the members of a household should be the same for all members of the household. If I do a normal imputation based on the person level data, the imputed values differ within one household.

**Question: How could I impute the same values within each household?**

One idea would be to impute the rent exclusively for the head of household and then take these values for the rest of the household as well. However, the imputation would then be based on much less observations and I am afraid that this would lead overall to worse imputation results.

For illustration, you can find an example below:

```
# Example data
N <- 1000
hh_id_short <- 1:(N / 5) # Household ID
y_short <- rnorm(N / 5, 1000, 100)

hh_id <- numeric()
y <- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(y_short)) {
  hh_id <- c(hh_id, rep(hh_id_short[i], 5))
  y <- c(y, rep(y_short[i], 5))
}

x1 <- y + rnorm(N, 0, 500)
x2 <- y + rnorm(N, 0, 500)
x3 <- y + rnorm(N, 0, 500)
x4 <- y + rnorm(N, 0, 500)
x5 <- y + rnorm(N, 0, 500)

# Missings
y_miss <- sample(1:(N / 5), 20)
y[hh_id %in% y_miss] <- NA

data <- data.frame(hh_id, y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

# Imputation
library("mice")
imp <- mice(data, m = 1)
data_imp <- complete(imp) # Different values within household
```

Comment: Have you tried multilevel imputation? If i remember correctly, mice does provide some options.

Comment: Thank you IWS, great answer as always! I didnt know that this is possible with mice. I also found a good source about the topic, in case somebody else is interested: http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/docs/Utrecht-15MayCourse%20handout.pdf

Comment: Although this comment is about mice and R specifically, you could also look at the 'miceadds' package which offers some additional multilevel imputation models.